# System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: 'Unable to load the specified metadata resource.'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have WebApi solution which has WebApI project and DataModel project(Class Library).

DataModel project has WebApiDbModel.edmx.

Below is the connectionstring :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebApiDbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/WebApiDbModel.csdl|res://*/WebApiDbModel.ssdl|res://*/WebApiDbModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MachineName\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DbName;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have copied my connectionstring to **Web.config of WebApi project**.

When I run the project locally and make call using postman, I am getting below exception in DataModel project code:

**System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: 'Unable to load the specified metadata resource.**

I tried changing connectionstring portion as below:
**connectionString="metadata=res://*/** but this don't work.

Using VS 2017 and EF version is 6.1.3

Comment: It's a bizarre issue. I can't figure out why it's happening either.